# parsing text-files in powershell with where and select-string operators

Tags: optimization, powershell-2.0

recently I had to solve a problem reading a large amount of logfiles and picking specific chunks of text out of them.

With some trial and error I found a working solution but I'd like to know if there are better approaches.

These logfiles contain text-blocks, each  is introduced by a 'heading' followed by an unknown amount of entries and finished with an empty line. (Example below, the numbers are pseudo linenumbers)

```
35#   logevent1 
36#   entry1
37#   entry2 
38#   entry3 
39#
40#   logevent2 
41#   entry1 
42#   entry2
```

Thus I know the 'logevent'-tag I can retrieve the line with `$line = $logfile | Select-String -Pattern 'logevent1'` and with `$lineNumber = $line | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LineNumber` I have the first value to use `Get-Content` with range operator `[$x..$y]`.
In my example this would be **35**. But how do I get the first empty line behind the text block?

I tried to work with `Select-String -Pattern ''` but that gives an instant exception due to the string is empty. So I wrote he following function:

```
function Get-TextBlock([string]$filePath,$lineNumber)
{
    $startLine = ($lineNumber -1)
    $counter = 0
    $emptyLines = @()    
    Get-Content (Get-ChildItem $filePath) | ForEach-Object { 
        if( $_ -eq '' ) {
            $emptyLines += $counter; 
        }
        $counter++
    }
    $endLine = 0
    $counter = 0
    while( $endLine -le $startLine) {
        $endLine = ($emptyLines[$counter]); $counter++; 
    }
    $output += ((Get-ChildItem $filePath) | Get-Content)[$startLine..$endLine]
    return $output
}
```

As mentioned before the function works for me but I feel like there are much better and easier ways to perfrom this task.

The Output (after removing my pseudo-line-numbers ;) ) looks like this

```
PS F:\scripts\powershell> Get-TextBlock '.\function-test.txt' 35
logevent1
entry1
entry2 
entry3 


____________________________________________________________________________
```

Kind regards